# Excel VBA Web Scraper; text extracted with quotes

Tags: vba, excel

Hello Stackoverflow community.

I've created a web scraper in VBA in order to get Sector/Industry data for stock quotes from Yahoo! Finance website to my excel file. The problem is, while i have cell value, for example, **Technology**, the real text is **"Technology "** (found that out when i've copied and Ctrl-F that text). And functions like VLOOKUP or SUMIF are returning #N/A because of that, when used against cell value **Technology** on another worksheet. I'd be really grateful if somebody could help me out with this, as if i cant find the solution on my own yet. The macro is below.

```
Sub SectInd()

Sheet1.Activate
Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
browser.Visible = False

Dim Lastr As Integer: Lastr = Sheet1.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row


If Lastr > 2 Then

For a = 3 To Lastr
Dim Quote As String: Quote = Sheet1.Cells(a, 1).Value
Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/in?s=" & Quote & "+Industry"

the_start:

browser.Navigate (URL)

Do
DoEvents
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
browser.Quit
Set browser = Nothing
GoTo the_start:
End If

Loop Until browser.ReadyState = 4

WebText = browser.Document.Body.InnerText
If InStr(WebText, "Sector:") > 0 Then
WebText2 = Mid(WebText, InStr(WebText, "Sector:"), 100)
TextSector = Split(WebText2, Chr(10))(1)
TextIndustry = Split(WebText2, Chr(10))(4)
End If
Sheet1.Cells(a, 4).Value = TextSector
Sheet1.Cells(a, 5).Value = TextIndustry


Next a
End If

Sheet1.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

P.S. Debug.Print also returns text without quotes (i.e. **Technology**, not **"Technology "**)

Comment: Why not using a web query, instead of writing VBA ? http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-import-online-data-into-excel-2010-with-a-w.html

Comment: I really disagree with the Close vote someone made.

Comment: iDevlop, because this macro allows me to go through large number of quotes automatically:) Pretty neat when dealing with S&P500 or Nasdaq-100 components list.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code.  And I don't see where you are getting double quotes so it looks fine to me.

If you want to see if the quotes are actually part of the string then try inspecting the length.  The string "cat" has 5 letters if it has quotes and only 3 letters if any quotes visible are added by the IDE to illustrate that it is a string.

so use Len(TextSector) to find a string's length.

Comment: S Meaden, tried as you advised. The result returned by Len() equals text without quotes + one space, but the promblem is still present. http://s14.postimg.org/km2b71qht/Macro_Result.jpg I've tried to change formats, but it didnt work out =/

Comment: Perhaps you needs to use Trim() around strings so trailing spaces aren't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a couple of years ago but I used msxml2.xmlhttp instead of the IE object. Perhaps this code can help you.

```
Public Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" _
(ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Public Function getGoogPrice(symbol As String) As Variant
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim X As String, Y As Variant
    Dim sSearch As String
    strURL = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=" & symbol
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry (strURL)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "get", strURL, False
        .send
        X = .responseText
    End With
    symbol = UCase(symbol)
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    getGoogPrice = Split(Split(X, symbol)(UBound(Split(X, symbol))), """,""")(1)
End Function

Public Function getReutersPrice(symbol As String) As Variant
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim X As String
    Dim sSearch As String, myDIV As String, myPrice As String

    strURL = "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" & symbol 'NESN.VX"
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry (strURL)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "get", strURL, False
        .send
        X = .responseText
    End With
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    sSearch = "sectionQuoteDetail"
    myDIV = Mid(X, InStr(1, X, sSearch) + Len(sSearch))
    myDIV = Trim(Mid(myDIV, 1, InStr(1, myDIV, "</div>") - 1))
    Y = Split(myDIV, "</span>")
    myPrice = Mid(Y(1), InStrRev(Y(1), ">") + 1)
    myPrice = Replace(myPrice, Chr(13), "")
    myPrice = Trim(Replace(myPrice, Chr(9), ""))
    getReutersPrice = myPrice
End Function
```